# property x0 does not exist on type HierarchyNode?

Tags: typescript, d3.js

i am trying to create a d3 treemap v5 with typescript but i cannot convert it from js, this code works on js but not in typescript:

```
var cell = svg
  .selectAll('g')
  .data(root.leaves())
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'group')
  .attr('transform', function(d) {
    console.log('d ', d)
    return 'translate(' + d.x0 + ',' + d.y0 + ')';
  });
```

when i log d, those properties x0 and y0 exists on d arg, but i am getting an error:

> Property 'x0' does not exist on type 'HierarchyNode<{ id: string;
>   name: string; children: never[]; }>'

how do i make this work? i don't want to use any but i'm new in typescript?

Comment: Given just the code you posted, this comes down to guessing. Please provide some more information, most importantly, an excerpt of your data and the way you build the hierarchy and the treemap.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [d3 (v4) tree layout and typescript: Property 'x' does not exist on type 'HierarchyNode<IOrgChartNode>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45356346/d3-v4-tree-layout-and-typescript-property-x-does-not-exist-on-type-hierarc)